# How to code html forms which are complex?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have been given the task of coding the form below. I was planning to do it using tables, however my instructor told me to do it using **divs**, since it takes up more resources or something(I think he said it was intensive). I can do it using divs, but I think it is a waste of time because I could make the below form easily using tables(I mean quickly).

Any ideas as to how to proceed, what to use, **tables** or **divs** or some thing ***better*** ??

[image]

Comment: It's a matter of taste and convention. We can't tell you which to use. But if you want a good grade from this instructor ...

Comment: I have had a fair amount of luck using nested OL elements in IE8/FF3+. They add a little more semantic meaning than just a DIV and with block-inline can address a good number of scenarios. Avoid floats at all costs if possible. They are/were mostly just overused hacks for browsers with pathetic CSS support. One really useful thing about tables is col/row spans -- but see browser quirks. (Tables can also be styled well with CSS in modern browsers -- set default padding/spacing 0, first, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the form looks the way it should and validates valid HTML 4 or xhtml breeds, you're good to go unless your instructor def wants you to use divs and css to create the layout. I would recommend the latter if you really want to get proficient in modern practices using css based layouts. Good luck!

Comment: kk was helpful found this link too http://code.google.com/p/floatz/wiki/LayoutingForms

Answer (score 1):

They are not mutually exclusive.  You could use divs for the main panels and tables within the divs to layout controls and text.

Comment: +1 because ... not all "modern" browsers support CSS "table" display types (e.g. table-cell). If they did, then we might finally actually be free of `<table>` "except for displaying tabular data" :p